# form_open_multipart does not upload a file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to upload an image, through this form:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('posts/create'); ?>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Add Title" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Body</label>
    <textarea id="editor1" class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="Add Body" required></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <label>Category</label>
      <select name="category_id" class="form-control">
          <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $category['id']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></option>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <label>Upload Image</label>
      <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And when I send the information, and I check if the POST petition has the correct data. It doesn't.

[image]

It shows me all the inputs expect the file input...

This is the controller, is called Posts and the function is call create.

```
public function create() {
  $data['title'] = 'Create post';
  $data['categories'] = $this->post_model->get_categories();

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required');

  if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('posts/create', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
  } else {
    // Upload image
    $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/images/posts';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = 2048;
    $config['max_width'] = 2000;
    $config['max_height'] = 2000;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    # Here's where I print the request.
    print_r($_POST);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
      $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
      $post_image = 'noimage.jpg';
    } else {
      $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
      $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    }
    echo $post_image;

    /* $this->post_model->create_post($post_image);
    redirect('posts'); */
  }
}
```

The autoloader.php is configured correctly...

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form', 'text');
```

If someone needs the complete project, [here you go](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/ciblog.git)

I'm using Docker to run it, with `docker-compose up --build` you can test it.

Comment: The file is in te $_file array

Comment: I print $_FILES and it gives me the right file, check the code and you'll see the error

Comment: It’s the normal behavior that you don’t see the file input in post array. What is your error?

Comment: When I do click in the form, it does not send the file I've uploaded

Comment: Your form is part in the post array and part in the file array. Still don’t see the issue. It is the normal behavior. You say you see both arrays populated so what is the issue?

Comment: Watch the screenshot I send, that form does not send the file...

Comment: noimage.jpg is from echo $post_image

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code and it is working fine and here is the result of `var_dump($_FILES);`:

```
["userfile"]=>
array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "image.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(23) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpB54.tmp"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(493443)
}
```

No problem at all.

**BUT** keep in mind that you should give `$config['upload_path']` a relative path or an absolute path, so you may consider this `$config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/posts';` or better this `$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH'assets/images/posts';`

Comment: Did you test with docker? Because docker create a virtual environment... I think is not the same to xampp

Comment: The only difference between `xampp on windows` and `lamp on linux` whether it is on physical, virtual or a docker container is the permission on directories, so make sure that you give your directory the right permission (give it 777 for now) .. apart from that, everything in your code works fine.

Comment: I have 755 permissions to the html folder https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/ciblog/blob/master/Dockerfile I'm gonna try 777 and see what happens, thanks and happy New year!

Comment: In your application give this path `full_abs_path_to_your_app/assets/images/posts` a full permission with `chmod -R 777 DIR`, try and let me know, happy new year :)

Comment: Bro, the problem was the path, php throws me that the path is not right, I did not see it before, anyway thank you for all your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Edit the controller Posts.php and add:

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

Was the solution.